# Firestore REST API | How to use firestore rest api with postman

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a project where I've to allow my firestore's database available publicly. I'm using firebase to communicate with firestore. I've tried to follow some documentations but I'm not really understanding them. I'm referring the links below which I've seen...

[Firestore's Use REST API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)

[Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/)

For more better explanation to my question, I'm referring a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JOrXCCBQw0) which exactly demonstrates my goal (swift language code doesn't matter though), but that tutorial isn't working as it suppose to. This tutorial didn't covered the authentication part which is stucking me.

My current issue is I'm unable to authenticate with firestore when I'm hitting at

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/databases?key=MY_PROJECT_KEY

When I hit this URL with Postman I got these results.

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

I've also tried several other methods with post request and including a single logged in user's JWT token as token field in HTTP body but they also responded as 401.

So I'm trying to find what API keys I need to provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Firestore REST API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api):

> For authentication, the Cloud Firestore REST API accepts either a
> Firebase Authentication ID token or a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token.
>
> The token you provide affects your request's authorization:
>
> - Use Firebase ID tokens to authenticate requests from your application's users. For these requests, Cloud Firestore uses Cloud
>   Firestore Security Rules to determine if a request is authorized.
> - Use a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token and a service account to authenticate requests from your application, such as requests for
>   database administration. For these requests, Cloud Firestore uses
>   Identity and Access Management (IAM) to determine if a request is
>   authorized.

---

The doc then explains how to get a Firebase ID token or how to generate an access token by using a service account. You have to decide which approach to choose depending on your exact case (are you interacting with Firestore only via the REST API? Do you mix calls through a Client SDK -e.g. to the Firebase Auth service- with call to the API?).

---

> After you obtain either a Firebase ID token or a Google Identity OAuth
> 2.0 token, pass it to the Cloud Firestore endpoints as an `Authorization` header set to `Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}`.

---

Below is an example of getting a Firebase ID Token via the JS SDK, then build the header and call a Firestore API endpoint ([`runQuery`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery) for querying a collection) via the axios library:

```
  const payloadObj = {
    structuredQuery: {
      where: {...},
      orderBy: [
        {
          field: {
            fieldPath: 'name',
          },
          direction: 'ASCENDING',
        },
      ],
      from: [
        {
          collectionId: '...',
        },
      ],
      limit: 200000,
    },
  };

  const url =
    'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-projecty>/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery';

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword('test@gmail.com', '.....')
    .then((userCredential) => {
        return firebase
            .auth()
            .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true);
        })
    .then((token) => {
        callHeaders = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token };
        return axios({
            url: url,
            method: 'post',
            headers: callHeaders,
            data: payloadObj,
        });
    })
```

Comment: I tried this method with postman by first retrieving current user's new token generated with `auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(...)` then added `Authorization: Bearer {token}` in postman and hit on the url from your code and I again got 401, but the message was: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

Comment: If you follow my answer it should work. Can you share in your question the exact value of the request header? In addition note that the URL shall include `(default)` for the default DB: `'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project>/databases/(default)/...`

Comment: This is screenshot of my postman request: https://imgur.com/a/5A0eVj5

Comment: This worked, actually the problem was I was requesting complete database on behalf of a user which obviously isn't allowed when I tried to retrieve information related to that particular user it worked fine.